# Fresh install of Fedora IoT out of space while disk has free space

Tags: fedora

I have a fresh install of Fedora IoT and was going to run `rpm-ostree upgrade` when I got the following error:

```
error: While pulling fedora/stable/aarch64/iot: Writing content object: min-free-space-percent '3%' would be exceeded, at least 4.1 kB requested
```

I followed the [instructions](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/iot/physical-device-setup/#_manual_image_transfer_with_dd) and flashed a 16GB USB with `dd`:

```
xzcat Fedora-IoT-[version].raw.xz | sudo dd status=progress bs=4M of=/dev/XXX
```

Here's my output from `lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    1 14.3G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    1  501M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    1    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3   8:3    1  2.5G  0 part /var
                                /sysroot/ostree/deploy/fedora-iot/var
                                /usr
                                /etc
                                /
                                /sysroot
zram0  252:0    0  3.7G  0 disk [SWAP]
```

And `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           762M  8.8M  753M   2% /run
/dev/sda3       2.5G  1.7G  598M  75% /sysroot
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /tmp
/dev/sda2       974M  122M  786M  14% /boot
/dev/sda1       501M   33M  469M   7% /boot/efi
tmpfs           381M     0  381M   0% /run/user/0
```

To me it looks like there is space available but I don't know how to move forward and make it available to the system.

I couldn't find anything in the instructions or from searches online.

Comment: Using `dd` would copy the partitions exactly as they were provided on the image.  You seem to have a disk with a size of 14.3G but you only have partitions adding up to 4G (`/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2`, `/dev/sda3`).  There are instructions from the article you posted that mention using `arm-image-installer` with the option `--resizefs` to better utilize the entire space on the device.

Comment: @GracefulRestart Yeah the partitions aren't filling the space, but coming from Debian that's never been an issue with `dd`. Those probably set that up at first boot. I saw `arm-image-installer` option but it's not available in my repositories so `dd` was the more portable option.

Comment: If you remember how you did it in Debian, you could check if they add any extra steps but the general workflow IIRC would be to resize the last partition to the desired size (`fdisk` or `gparted`) and then extend the filesystem on that partition to fill the unused space (`resize2fs` if using an `ext[234]` filesystem).

Comment: @GracefulRestart No difference in the usage so I assume it's handled at boot, I've only ever done Debian and Raspberry Pi OS on metal and this issue has never come up.

Yes, resizing was my initial thought too but being new to Fedora and ostree I didn't want to get ahead of myself and break anything. I took a closer look at `arm-image-installer` and it's just a shell script so I'll use that instead for now.